# The exponential integrals are the functions $E_n$ defined by $E_n(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}(e^{xt}t^n)^{-1}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, numerical-methods

[image]

**In the response of the book says:** *Hint:* Determine whether $E_n(x)$ is increasing or decreasing as a function of $n$

But I do not know how to interpret this help.

Any help or answer to this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the integrands at $n = N$ and at $n = N+1$?  Doing so will tell you whether this is increasing or decreasing as a function of $n$.

Comment: @EricTowers What is the use of proving that it is increasing or decreasing?

Answer (score 2):

> Determine whether $E_n(x)$ is increasing or decreasing as a function of $n$.

It simply means that for any $x>0$ and $n\ge0$, we must have $E_{n+1}(x)\ge E_n(x)$. This is quite easy, since for any $t>1$, we have $(e^{xt}t^{n+1})^{-1}\ge(e^{xt}t^n)^{-1}$, and thus

$$\int_1^\infty(e^{xt}t^{n+1})^{-1}{\rm~d}t\ge\int_1^\infty(e^{xt}t^n)^{-1}{\rm~d}t\\\implies E_{n+1}(x)\ge E_n(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

For every $x>0$, $(E_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ is a sequence.

For a fixed $x>0$, the sequence is increasing if $E_{n+1}(x)\geq E_n(x)$ for every $n\geq 0$. Same idea for decreasing

The nice thing about this specific recurrence relation is that you can see that the increasing/decreasing part independent of the choice of $x>0$, so the $x$ is not important for determining if the sequence is increasing/decreasing.